# how to find duplicate dropdown row in a table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

There is a table which contains an user dropdown per row. Needs to prevent of selecting duplicate users of dropdown in the table.

[image]

While selecting the duplicate user in the above table as "easy",The js code should keep the first of user dropdowm the rest of duplicate user dropdown wants to remove from table.

HTML
[image]

Javascript Code

```
function  checkDuplicateUserId(obj){
  var user_id=$("#"+obj.id+" option:selected").val();            
  $('tbody#data tr select').each(function (i, row) {
  if ($('tbody#data tr select').find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').size() > 1) {
      alert();
  } 

  });

}

function  checkAlreadySelected(obj){
    checkDuplicateUserId(obj);
    var num = parseInt($(obj).attr('num'));
    var user_id=$("#"+obj.id+" option:selected").val();            
    var next_user_id=$("#user_id_"+eval(num+1)+" option:selected").val();          
    if(user_id && typeof next_user_id == 'undefined'){
        var row = updateSrNo(num);
        $("#data").append(row);
    }

   }
```

As i mentioned in the js code, I have written a function as called as **checkDuplicateUserId()** to detect the duplicate dropdown from the table, Unfortunately the **alert()** not prompted while select the duplicate users.

What's the issue of jquery code which i have written wrongly there?
If you have other way to accomplish this, Please say it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put all your code in a JS Fiddle and share the link. That way it'd be much easier because we need your HTML code(not image)

Comment: It would be easier for the user to understand if you disable the selections rather than remove them.  It will probably be easier for you to implement as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
function  checkAlreadySelected(obj){
  var user_id=$("#"+obj.id+" option:selected").val();            
  $('tbody#data tr select').each(function (i, row) {
  if ($(this).val()==user_id) {
      return false ;
  } 

  });
  return true ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function  checkDuplicateUserId(obj){
  var user_id=$("#"  +obj.id + " option:selected").val();            

  if( $('tbody#data tr select option:selected').filter( function(){ if( $(this).val() == user_id ) return true; } ).length > 1) {
    alert('something');
  }
}
```